# PHP: Get binary value for SHA hash

Tags: php

I want to get the binary value for a SHA256 hash:

```
echo hash("SHA256", "x" , true);
// -qB�&�Db|���2��S��<��%��H�
```

I would expect something like "010111001000[..]" (256 bits in total).

Is there a function to convert the funny looking string to a "string of bits"?

Thank you!

Comment: The third parameter `true` is for `raw_output`, may wanna switch that to false. Or don't pass it in completely, it `false` by default anyway.

Comment: Why do you expect / think you need output like that?

Comment: @Andrew that doesn't do what OP expects. That returns the hex representation of the binary string. To what is being show to you are bytes not bits. But the chance you actually need to bit representation for something is really not that big. What is it you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you need it?? Could not find any inbuilt functions!!

Comment: Hello, the "Show the 8 bits of a byte in PHP" answer does not really work / help. :(

Comment: This is not just byte conversion.

Comment: @SubinThomas Why not?

Comment: My bad. I was not thinking of a for loop there!!

Comment: @Tream why do you think it doesn't help? That's exactly what you are asking to do